# Can you choose asp.net runtime in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

We've upgraded the asp.net runtime from 2.0 to 4.0 - turns out a vendor provided control has breaking changes. Our entire site is on asp.net runtime 4.0. Is it possible to use asp.net runtime 2.0 for a few controls (using some directive) or a folder (using web.config)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each application pool must use only one version of the runtime, and that is configured within IIS.

I agree with @DanielAWhite - your vendor needs a lesson in software design.

[See this MSDN article for comments regarding application pool configuration and CLR versions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx)

> You must make sure that all applications that are assigned to an
>   application pool target the CLR that the application pool is
>   associated with. If you assign an application to an application pool
>   that is associated with a different CLR version than the application
>   targets, run-time errors will result.

You *can*, however, have multiple applications within a site that are split into separate folders, and assign a different app pool to each application, which will let you use different CLR versions within the same site.

Comment: We are using DLLs of both 2.0 and 4 within same application pool.

Comment: @AlexDN Really? According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx, and according to IIS Manager, each app pool has to reference a single version of the CLR. Now, using components that are compiled against different versions of the framework may be a different matter.

Comment: See comments for my answer. We are using only compiled DLLs of .NET 2.0

Comment: @AlexDN You can use up to v3.5 DLLs within the same app, but the docs specifically state (confirmed by a test I just ran) that v4 and v2 can't run in the same process. If you're only using 2.0 assemblies, why do you say that you're running v4 and v2 in the same process?

Comment: Because we use web controls of compiled .NET 2 DLLs on pages of site that runs .NET 4.0 with render compatibility to 3.5.

Comment: Gentlemen, I think the following link might be helpful, see the section "Adding Custom Web Server Controls".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398791.aspx If you have a project that is targeting 4.0, you can (attempt to) use custom controls targeting older versions.  However, as OP has pointed out, there can be compatibility problems because the old controls will use upgraded framework components when run within the newer environment.

Answer (score 1):

you would need two different app pools because the .NET Framework version is defined per appPool in IIS, I think having two folders with different web.config and using two different app pools could work, but keep in mind that it will be more like having two web applications working separately and not working as one app only.

can't you change the component given by that criminal obsolete horrible vendor which thinks to force you to still use .NET 2.0 in 2012?

Comment: I wish we could, but this is unfortunately a very important component.

Answer (score 1):

David Lively is correct about your direct question.  The proper action is probably to run the site in 2.0 for now.  You could also look at segmenting the site into two application pools if the control(s) in question only appear in a small area.

I just wanted to make sure, though, that you you know of the `<system.web><pages>` `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` attribute ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx)).  If the control will work on Framework 3.5 (which uses ASP.NET 2.0 runtime), perhaps this will help with the breaking change.

Comment: pseudocoder, thank you - was aware of the option, tried, but didn't help my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

We are running the .NET 2 and 4 assemblies within same site without problems on IIS 7. I'm not sure, but you may have problems on IIS 6 since it can not run multiple framework versions at the same time. What kind of problem you have? If it's client issues, try to set in web config render compatibility to 3.5. If it not help, then you can set target framework in web.config to 3.5, but whole your site will work on 3.5.

Comment: same site is one thing, but I do believe you have two web application inside it with two different app pools, right?

Comment: We are using Obout webcontrol version 2.0 on web site that running on .NET 4 pool. In addition we have Dundas charts version 2.0 (they do not support and sell new versions any more) on the same site. At the last, we use MS Enterprise Library .NET 2 for our Data Access Layer. All this is on application pool .NET 4 and working fine :)

Comment: @Alex Dn Running forward-compatible code on ASP.NET 4 is not the same as running some code in one version and some code in another.

Comment: @pseudocoder Yes, i think you are right, thats why I asked what kind of problems he has.

Comment: @AlexDn - the problem is on the client side, a very specific property is not accessible. Vendor's customer support confirmed the breaking change. We tried targetting 3.5, but it has not helped us. Thank you.